# About Keil software simulation

Tags: c, arm, embedded, stm32, embedded-resource

I have problem with NVIC registers in Keil.
in my data sheet NVIC starts with NVIC_ISERx

[image]

[image]

But in keil starts with ICTR register

[image]

So I have problem with matching addresses

Comment: it is just showing some other control registers, you can see ISER registers in that table.  those others are related to interrupts so perhaps the kiel folks felt like including them here to be helpful.

Comment: the doc you shows does not include the address mapping so what is the problem?

Comment: Anyway you can always try to access a register at a given address, modify the value and see if the result is what you expected or not

Comment: Register Like ISER0 hase an offest 0x000 But in Keil has 0x100

Comment: @old_timer
i updated question

Comment: if you look at the arm documentation you will see the base address if ISER registers (which is also ISER0) is 0xE000E100 when you add 0x0000 to that you get 0xE000E100.

Comment: As shown ICER0 at 0xE000E180 and so on.

Comment: If you select each register in the NVIC viewer, the address of the register is clear;y displayed in the text at the bottom on the view window.  Making it rather simple for "matching addresses".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Here in the ARM documentation, can't do much with these registers without the ARM documentation.

0xE000E100 + 0x000 = 0xE000E100.

Likewise 0xE000E004 is the address to ICTR.

Comment: Thank You
i have another question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63638224/stm32f103c4-in-keil-software-simulation

Answer (score 1):

the order of the properties is not the same as the order in the peripheral.

It is clearly visible here:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you 
i have another question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63638224/stm32f103c4-in-keil-software-simulation