# STM32F103C4 in keil software simulation

Tags: c, arm, embedded, stm32

I'm trying to enable interrupt in STM32F103C4
and start to debug session in Keil

```
    NVIC_voidEnableInterrupt(6);
    NVIC_voidSetPenddingFlag(6);
```

Before enabling Interrupt NVIC registers working fine

[image]

But when I'm trying writing in ISER0 it writing also on ICER0 So interrupt disabled again

[image]

and doesn't write on ISPR0

[image]

Register Description

```
#define NVIC_ISER           ((volatile u32 *) 0xE000E100+ 0x000)
#define NVIC_ICER           ((volatile u32 *) 0xE000E100+ 0x080)
#define NVIC_ISPR           ((volatile u32 *) 0xE000E100+ 0x100)
#define NVIC_ICPR           ((volatile u32 *) 0xE000E100+ 0x180)
#define NVIC_IABR           ((volatile u32 *) 0xE000E100+ 0x200)
#define NVIC_IPR            ((volatile u32 *) 0xE000E100+ 0x300)
#define NVIC_STIR           ((volatile u32 *) 0xE000E100+ 0xE00)
```

Enable Fun :

```
void NVIC_voidEnableInterrupt  ( u8 Copy_u8IntNumber )
{
 if(Copy_u8IntNumber <= 31)
 {
    NVIC_ISER[0] = (1 << Copy_u8IntNumber);
 }
 else if (Copy_u8IntNumber <= 59 )
 {
    Copy_u8IntNumber -= 32 ; 
    SET_BIT(NVIC_ISER[1] , Copy_u8IntNumber ); 
 }
 else 
 {
    /*   <TODO> ERROR OUT OF INTERRUPT NUMBERS  */
 }

}
```

Pending Flag Fun

```
void NVIC_voidSetPenddingFlag  ( u8 Copy_u8IntNumber )
{
 if(Copy_u8IntNumber <= 31)
 {

    SET_BIT(NVIC_ISPR[0] , Copy_u8IntNumber ); 
 }
 else if (Copy_u8IntNumber <= 59 )
 {
    Copy_u8IntNumber -= 32 ; 
    SET_BIT(NVIC_ISPR[1] , Copy_u8IntNumber ); 
 }
 else 
 {
    /*   <TODO> ERROR OUT OF INTERRUPT NUMBERS  */
 }      
}
```

Bit Math

```
#define SET_BIT(VAR,BIT)    VAR |= (1 << (BIT))
#define CLR_BIT(VAR,BIT)    VAR &= ~(1 << (BIT))
```

Comment: @old_timer setting pending flag for chack NVIC driver.
For set bit i can use it instead of NVIC_ISER[0] = (1 << Copy_u8IntNumber); 
in this case two correct beacuse 0 has no effect on ISER

Comment: @old_timer that's my first-time use Keil simulation but in all ways there is no interrupt happens

Comment: You used the typecast wrong this is an elementary C thing, add more parenthesis.

Comment: The procedure of reseting the bits in many of whose registers is not as trivial. Many require writing 1 to clear the bit. Another are write only etc etc. Generally speaking your definitions will fail in many cases. Use ARM CMSIS definitions and functions to handle it correctly